# how to disable Application Menu in top bar in 20.04?

Tags: gnome, 20.04, appearance, menu-bar

In the past there used to be an option in Settings->Appearance->Behavior to toggle between using the Application Menu in the top menu bar and a window-specific menu button.

In 20.04, I don't see that option anymore.  Not in settings, and not in gnome-tweaks.

This is an example of the menu that I'd like to move down from the top of the screen into the application's window:

[image]

Can someone tell me how to do this in Ubuntu 20.04?